# Нужна помощь растягивании блока внутри другого блока

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Content,
.LeftBar,
.RightBar,
.ContentBlock {
  display: block;
}

.Content {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 2;
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 1500px;
}

.LeftBar {
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  background: #770000;
  width: 16%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.LeftBarName {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.LeftBarMenu {
  background: #a50000;
  height: 300px;
}

.LeftBarMenu table tr td {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: White;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
}

.RightBar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  background: #770000;
  width: 16%;
  /*16%*/
  height: 1300px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.ContentBlock {
  float: left;
  width: 68%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Content">
  <div class="LeftBar">
    <div class="LeftBarName">
      <p align="middle">
        <h1><b>Игры</b></h1></p>
    </div>
    <div class="LeftBarMenu">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p><b> Tera</b></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a id="LMenuLinks" href="Auction.php">
              <p><b>Black Desert</b></p>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContentBlock">///
  </div>
  <div class="RightBar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы левый блок `LeftBar` растягивался по горизонтали до конца родительского блока, а также чтобы растягивался `RightBar` с учетом того, что на сайте ниже родительского блока еще находится подвал?
Позиционированием пробовал, но ничего не смог сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.Content,
.LeftBar,
.RightBar,
.ContentBlock {
  display: block;
}

.Content {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 2;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1500px;
}

.LeftBar {
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  background: #770000;
  width: 16%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.LeftBarName {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.LeftBarMenu {
  background: #a50000;
  height: 300px;
}

.LeftBarMenu table tr td {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: White;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
}

.RightBar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  background: #770000;
  width: 16%;
  /*16%*/
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.ContentBlock {
  float: left;
  width: 68%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Content">
  <div class="LeftBar">
    <div class="LeftBarName">
      <p align="middle">
        <h1><b>Игры</b></h1></p>
    </div>
    <div class="LeftBarMenu">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p><b> Tera</b></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a id="LMenuLinks" href="Auction.php">
              <p><b>Black Desert</b></p>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContentBlock">///
  </div>
  <div class="RightBar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да ,оно ,Спасибо